# Problems with CUDA on Windows10 + Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cuda, nvidia, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a laptop with Nvidia GPU - MX250, and I would like to write and execute code, written with CUDA. I have an Ubuntu 20.04 LTS emulator installed on the Windows 10, namely this application from Microsoft store - https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/ubuntu-on-windows#1-overview.

I have installed the `nvcc` toolkit, and the installed version is

`nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation Built on Sun_Jul_28_19:07:16_PDT_2019 Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.2431`

I am trying to run the basic samples, like the canonical vec_add sample from the official tutorial. The code compiles without issues, however, during runtime, after wrapping the code with the following macro:

```
#define CATCH_ERROR(rhs) cudaError_t status = rhs; \
if(rhs != cudaSuccess)  printf("%s", cudaGetErrorString(status));

// Allocate vectors in device memory
CATCH_ERROR(cudaMalloc(&d_a, size));
cudaMalloc(&d_b, size);
cudaMalloc(&d_c, size);
```

I receive a message - `no CUDA-capable device is detected`. Correct me, if I am wrong, but as far as I understand, the NVIDIA drivers for UNIX usually come with the nvidia-cuda-toolkit. What can I do, to make the Ubuntu see the GPU, or there is no way do this on Ubuntu subsystem installed above the Windows 10.

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: perhaps more importantly, I'm not familiar with the emulator (perhaps it uses WSL?  I don't know.) but a linux  "emulator" on windows may not be able to access the GPU at all, and if you are on WSL you would need to follow specific steps to enable the GPU for CUDA using WSL.

Comment: @RobertCrovella yes, it uses WSL, i've found a specific version of drivers for Ubuntu emulator, I hope it will work, thanks for the comment

Comment: To get CUDA GPU access within WSL, you should follow the instructions [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl-user-guide/index.html).  Note that the functionality is currently in a preview status, and you need a specific driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This suggestion is an alternative to try without emulator

https://sourceforge.net/projects/toysbox/files/bionic-nvidia/ubuntu-20.04-5.4.0-26-generic-nvidia-450.57-primeselect.iso

it is live iso-image with nvidia-450.57 installed so you can run your cuda directly ;the only requirement is to set PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH to make it awared of your cuda runtime path ; in particular don't forget a link so cuda seems to find its compiler at /usr/local/cuda/bin

just use it on usb stick or simply boot from iso image using grub loopback mechanism.

hoan